# GetClientUTC returns null value

Tags: c#, utc

In C#, when I'm trying to get the current time of a page using UTC Time.
I get an empty value. I first thought the issue might be related to a runat="server" property being incorrectly set, or the browser not correctly accepting cookies. However, neither appears to be the issue. Does this mean I am missing a key somewhere?

Any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Where are you setting `Session["GetClientUTC"]`?  If you don't set it, of course it won't exist.

Comment: So you have a hidden control you read the time out of? Why are you putting it in session at all? Why not just use the value of that control? If you want us to help, you're going to have to at least tell us what kind of control that is.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing appears in Session object by itself. You need to put value there first. As result non-existing keys return empty (null) result.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where you have this code snippet from, but you have to set values in the `Session` object by yourself somewhere. If you want to get the offset of the clients clock to UTC, you could have a look at this site here: [Getting the client UTC Offset with ASP.NET](http://rsanidad.wordpress.com/2007/09/21/getting-the-client-utc-offset-with-aspnet/)

Of course, at the time you deliver the first page, you can not know the clients time. Also, if the client has javascript disabled you will never get the info. In this case, you have to either 'guess' the offset, or use some default, like your servers time.

Comment: I'm trying to get the client's current time. Javascript is not disabled.

Comment: Then the method provided in the link above is just what you are looking for. It gives you the offset of the clients clock to UTC. Together with the current time of your server and this offset you can calculate the time at the client.

Answer (score 0):

Session doesn't auto-populate, so if you're manually putting that in there, we'll need some more context about where and when.

I'm not clear on why you're looking to the session collection for the time though.

When you say "the current time of a page", what are you talking about? Do you just want the current time? That's `DateTime.UtcNow`. Or are you looking for the time the client's clock is set to?